# Referencing the WinHTTP.dll via Delphi

Tags: delphi, http, com, activex

I've been wondering how to use HTTP requests since I first started Delphi.
I don't want to use any alternative HTTP libraries because I'm accustomed to the use of WinHTTP (the DLL, not lib).

So can anyone try to explain to me how to reference / use it via Delphi?
In Visual Basic.NET all you have to do is select the component from a palette.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a port of both WinHttp.dll and WinINet.dll.

See `TWinHttp` and `TWinINet` classes defined in [SynCrtSock.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrtSock.pas). They allow direct access of those libraries

Here are the low-level conversion used by TWinHTTP:

```
{ TWinHTTP }

const
  winhttpdll = 'winhttp.dll';

  WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY = 0;
  WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH = $00000100;
  WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE = $00800000;
  WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_COALESCE = $40000000;
  WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER = $20000000;

function WinHttpOpen(pwszUserAgent: PWideChar; dwAccessType: DWORD;
  pwszProxyName, pwszProxyBypass: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD): HINTERNET; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpConnect(hSession: HINTERNET; pswzServerName: PWideChar;
  nServerPort: INTERNET_PORT; dwReserved: DWORD): HINTERNET; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect: HINTERNET; pwszVerb: PWideChar;
  pwszObjectName: PWideChar; pwszVersion: PWideChar; pwszReferer: PWideChar;
  ppwszAcceptTypes: PLPWSTR; dwFlags: DWORD): HINTERNET; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpCloseHandle(hInternet: HINTERNET): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest: HINTERNET; pwszHeaders: PWideChar; dwHeadersLength: DWORD;
  dwModifiers: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest: HINTERNET; pwszHeaders: PWideChar;
  dwHeadersLength: DWORD; lpOptional: Pointer; dwOptionalLength: DWORD; dwTotalLength: DWORD;
  dwContext: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest: HINTERNET;
  lpReserved: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest: HINTERNET; dwInfoLevel: DWORD; pwszName: PWideChar;
  lpBuffer: Pointer; var lpdwBufferLength, lpdwIndex: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
function WinHttpReadData(hRequest: HINTERNET; lpBuffer: Pointer;
  dwNumberOfBytesToRead: DWORD; var lpdwNumberOfBytesRead: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external winhttpdll;
```

In the very same unit, you've also the `THttpApiServer` class implementing an HTTP server using fast *http.sys* kernel-mode server.

From my tests, I found out the `TWinHttp / THttpApiServer` classes to be the faster HTTP solution around, with much less overhead than Indy or Synapse components, and with some nice features like native HTTPS.

For those how don't know about WinHttp.dll, it is much faster than WinINet.dll (which can be dead slow). As result, `TWinHttp` is **much** faster than `TWinINet`, and is quite as fast as low level direct call to *WinSocks*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exported functions of any DLL in Delphi code. As an example, this is how you use the [`WinHttpConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384091%28VS.85%29.aspx) function:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses WinInet;

...

function WinHttpConnect(hSession: HINTERNET; pswzServerName: PChar;
  nServerPort: INTERNET_PORT; dwReserved: cardinal): HINTERNET; stdcall;

...

implementation

...

function WinHttpConnect; external 'Winhttp.dll' name 'WinHttpConnect';

...
```

You don't even need to add `uses WinInet`. If you don't, you need to know that

```
type
  HINTERNET = pointer;
  INTERNET_PORT = word;
```